# "Invalid field name" (PHP's pg_insert)

Tags: php, psql

I've been using PHP's pg_insert function to automatically insert the values of lengthy associative arrays into a PSQL database.  Lately, however, the following error has been appearing.

> PHP Notice:  pg_insert() [function.pg-insert]: >Invalid field name (testing) in values in [filename] on line 87

I've looked around, but I can't find any documentation on what this error means.

Comment: show us the code which make this error

Comment: pg_insert($conn, $userTimesheetName, $finalarray);  

$finalarray is an associative array, and $userTimesheetName is the name of the database table.

Comment: If I replace the aforementioned code with the following, it works:

$result = pg_query("INSERT INTO timesheetBob (task, intime, outtime, mdt) VALUES ('".$finalarray['task']."', '".$finalarray['intime']."', '".$finalarray['outtime']."', '".$finalarray['mdt']."');") or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

Comment: in $finalarray, have you something else than the 4 fields ?

Comment: Nope.  Just the four.

Comment: so you have no idea from where this "testing" come from ? have you displayed all the variables to be sure they contain what you expect

Comment: Add the code to the question.